# How to create subdomain on linode?

Tags: apache, linode

I have bought a domain(larasteps.com) from Godaddy. I have successfully setup my website for practice. Now I want to add subdomain dev.larasteps.com. I read many articles that say that I should create a A/AAAA  record in Linode.Then I created A/AAAA record and entered Hostname value dev  and ip address to the IP that linode provided me. Then I installed laravel and setup virtualhost for it. Virtualhost file name is dev.larasteps.com.conf where I mentioned the path for the developer project. Then I enabled this conf file. I also disabled the default conf file.

After saving the changes I have waited for almost 30 hours but sub-domain did not work.

Then I saw in a forum that I should create a CNAME record where I have added hostname 'dev' and Aliases To 'dev.larasteps.com' and saved changes.   But it seems like this is also not working.

Can anybody correct my mistake ? I'm sure that something important is being missed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just added a subdomain to my linode. Here are the steps I followed.

1- Added a A/AAAA record to my parent domain and pointed to the IP address of my linode server from the DNS manager of linode.

2- Changed the config on my nginx to handle the new subdomain created and pointed it to the right internal IP (localhost:port)

3- Waited for a few minutes and it works.

I would suggest you recheck the config of whichever server (apache/nginx) you are using and make sure it is handling the new subdomain that you have created. From linode's end just adding a A/AAAA record was all I needed.

Comment: Thanks Anshul, do I have to do anything in godaddy for setting up sub-domain ?

Comment: No, I did not add any new config to godaddy to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks. may be I have other issue with sub-domain settings.